# Android dialog box with PIN input

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to do a PIN input as a dialog.
This part is working fine. But when I enter my pin and try to compare it to my requested pin it just closes my dialog.

So here is my code:
PinInput.java

```
package com.ts.techassi.ts;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class PinInput extends DialogFragment {
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "tuerschild.saschalautenschlaege.tuerschild.MESSAGE";
    Context context;
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.pin_input, null));
        Log.i("LOL", "Started");

        builder.setMessage("Enter PIN")
                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        Uri url = readUrl();
                        Dialog f = (Dialog) dialog;
                        // String ts_id = url.getLastPathSegment();
                        EditText pin = (EditText)f.findViewById(R.id.pin);
                        TextView test = (TextView) f.findViewById(R.id.response);
                        String pinString = pin.getText().toString();

                        try {
                            String response = new Http().execute().get();
                            // Log.i("test", response);
                            if( response == pinString) {
                                Boolean isLauncher = isMyAppLauncherDefault();
                                if(isLauncher == true){
                                    resetPreferredLauncherAndOpenChooser(context);
                                }
                            } else {
                                PinInput.this.getDialog().cancel();
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Log.i("Test",e.toString());
                        }
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Abbrechen", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // User cancelled the dialog
                    }
                });
        return builder.create();
    }

    public Uri readUrl() {
        String fileDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/dbDoorsign/url.txt";

        File file = new File(fileDirectory);

        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
        ;

        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String line;

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                text.append(line);
            }
            br.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {

        }
        return Uri.parse(text.toString());
    }

    private boolean isMyAppLauncherDefault() {
        final IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        filter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);

        List<IntentFilter> filters = new ArrayList<IntentFilter>();
        filters.add(filter);

        final String myPackageName = getActivity().getPackageName();
        List<ComponentName> activities = new ArrayList<ComponentName>();
        final PackageManager packageManager = (PackageManager) getActivity().getPackageManager();

        packageManager.getPreferredActivities(filters, activities, null);

        for (ComponentName activity : activities) {
            if (myPackageName.equals(activity.getPackageName())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static void resetPreferredLauncherAndOpenChooser(Context context) {
        PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
        ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(context, FakeLauncherActivity.class);
        packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

        Intent selector = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        selector.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        selector.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, "1");
        selector.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(selector);

        packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DEFAULT, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    }

}
```

My second file Http.java

```
package com.ts.techassi.ts;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;


public class Http extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";
    private TextView scanResults;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {

        try {
            return sendGet();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return e.toString();
        }
    }

    private String sendGet() throws Exception {

        String url = "http://my.url.com";

        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        // optional default is GET
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");

        //add request header
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        // print result
        // System.out.println(response.toString());
        return response.toString();

    }


}
```

EDIT 1:

Changed `if( pinString == response)` to `if( pinString.equals(response))`

So I thinks thats all you need. I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```
if( response == pinString) {
```

Never compare Strings like this in Java. Change it to:

```
if( pinString.equals(response) ) {
```

The reason is that, in Java, == operator compares instances, not contents. It works for primitives (like ints and longs), but Objects, including Strings, need to be compared with the .equals() method, which compares **the contents, not the instance**.

Comment: I tried that, but doesn't seem to make a differrence.

Comment: Can you paste this above the if line and tell me what it prints? Log.i("StackOverflow", String.format("response: %s, pinString: %s", response, pinString));

Comment: Mhm I did, but in my logcat isn't showing anything. The only thing I noticed is: `03-08 11:39:51.070 23946-23946/com.ts.techassi.ts E/Parcel: Reading a NULL string not supported here.`

Comment: Discovered this now: `03-08 14:32:53.054 1162-1162/? W/SurfaceFlinger: couldn't log to binary event log: overflow.`

Comment: Can u help me with that?